# Why does this code output a list of "None"?

Tags: python

```
fibonacci = [0, 1]
fibonacci = [fibonacci.append(fibonacci[i - 1] + fibonacci[i - 2]) for i in range(2, 11)]
print(fibonacci)
```

This code is supposed to print a list of the first 10 fibonacci numbers. I copied it from another question, but it doesn't seem to work. Why is this?

Comment: Because you're putting the result of `append` in a list, and `append` returns None. Either use `append` _or_ use a list comprehension.

Comment: You can get it to work by not assigning fibonacci to the list comprehension i.e. just have `[fibonacci.append(fibonacci[i - 1] + fibonacci[i - 2]) for i in range(2, 11)]` though it's discouraged to use list comprehension just for side effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append will return `None`. So remove the assignment to the same variable. It will work.

```
In [11]: fibonacci = [0, 1] 
    ...: [fibonacci.append(fibonacci[i - 1] + fibonacci[i - 2]) for i in range(2, 11)]                                                                                                                      
Out[11]: [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]

In [12]: print(fibonacci)                                                                                                                                                                                   
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you love one-liners, in my opinion it makes more sense to write it this way:

```py
fibonacci = [0, 1]
for i in range(2, 11):
    fibonacci.append(fibonacci[i - 1] + fibonacci[i - 2])
```